# Magento log() in upgrade/setup doesn't work

Tags: php, magento

On the Windows, Linux OS I have problem, doesn't work Mage::log() ::logException()
because Magento says the var/log/active is 0 but in database is 1 for General, website and 1 is for store.
This problem exists in sql/upgrade(or/and)install file in own module on the Magento Community I tested 1.7+ to 1.8.1 .

Helps only turned on development mode or force flag but only for ::log() function.
Could someone help?

Comment: So you saying Save Log is No in Admin and it is one when looking db table. Clear cache, flush it and try again.

Comment: You didn't understand me. If You are in Admin and looking at var/log/active it is enabled but for NameSpace/SomeModule/sql/xyz_setup/upgrade(or install) file the config path 'var/log/active' is always 0 EDIT: I cleared cache many times and problem exist still. Edit 2: The problem is with start Magento and loadin first/pre configuration.